# Query for all records from 1:01 AM two days ago to 1 AM yesterday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to write a query as part of an SSIS package, and part of the requirements is that the query will return all rows with a time stamp (currently in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm format) occuring from 1:01 AM 2 days ago to 1 AM 1 day ago. I can write this for dates, but I'm stuck on how to incorporate the hour range. Current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT dateadd(S, logintime, '1970-01-01') as "conversion"
,DATEPART(hh, dateadd(HOUR, logintime, '1970-01-01')) as "HourCol"
,DATEPART(hh, dateadd(MINUTE, logintime, '1970-01-01')) as "MinuteCol"
, * FROM my.logtable
WHERE row_date between dateadd(day, -3, getdate()) and DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) as subselect
where conversion between --and from here I'm lost.
order by conversion
```

Comment: Show us what have you try to get the dates? Then we help you including the hours.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).  And clarify if the column in question is (correctly) stored as a date/time or (incorrectly) stored as a string.

Comment: edited because I forgot to paste in my current query.

Comment: the logintime column is an int, unix timestamp starting from jan 01 1970. I made the conversion alias just to have something more human-readable and easy to use. I believe conversion makes a datetime? unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT getdate() today,
       CAST(getdate() as DATE) today_0000,       
       DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(getdate() as DATE)) yesterday0000,
       DATEADD(day, -2, CAST(getdate() as DATE)) daybeforyesterday0000,
       DATEADD(mi, 60, CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(getdate() as DATE)) as datetime)) yesterday0100,
       DATEADD(mi, 61, CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, CAST(getdate() as DATE)) as datetime)) daybeforyesterday0101
```

Last two give you the range you are looking for. As long you compare with another datetime should work.

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to, when I use the conversion column I made to compare. Thank you!